# How to flatten a nested string?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column with data type string and it has nested key value pairs. I want to extract each key:value pair as a columnname:values.

The data looks like -

```
ID    attributes
1     {"category":"ABC","region":US,"item_id":[1,2,3]}
2     {"category":"PQR","region":EU,"item_id":[3,4,5]}
```

I want to separate these key-value pairs into different columns. The output should be as follows-

```
ID    category      region      item_id
1       ABC           US        [1,2,3]
2       PQR           EU        [3,4,5]
```

How to achieve this output? I tried using UNNEST but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select id, arr[offset(0)] key, arr[offset(1)] value 
  from your_table, unnest(split(translate(attributes, '{}', ''), ',"')) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ':') as arr)])
)
pivot (min(value) for key in ('category', 'region', 'item_id'))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: this gives an error - "Column arr of type ARRAY cannot be used as an implicit grouping column of a PIVOT clause at [6:1]"

Comment: i tested above with this data: `with your_table as (
  select 1 id, '{"category":"ABC","region":US,"item_id":[1,2,3]}' attributes union all
  select 2, '{"category":"PQR","region":EU,"item_id":[3,4,5]}'
)` - try again and let me know! also - have you tried my answer ias is  - or you modified it?

Comment: @user11035754 - have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a dataframe from the list of dicts in your desired out format, with python list comprehension inside of a dataframe create statement:

```
import pandas as pd
outpd = pd.DataFrame([x for x in mydata['attributes']])
print(outpd)  
  category region    item_id
0      ABC     US  [1, 2, 3]
1      PQR     EU  [3, 4, 5]
```